# Create a column Status based on the conditions on different states in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6)
States <- c(NA,NA,"All Locked","All Not Locked","All Locked","All Locked"
                   ,"All Not Locked","All Not Locked","All Not Locked")
ToolID <- c(NA,NA,"SWP","SWP","SWP","SWP","SWP","SWP","SWP")
Measurement <- c("Length","Breadth","Width","Height","Time","Time"
                   ,"Time","Mass","Mass")
Location <- c("US","US","UK","UK","US","US","US","UK","UK")

df1 <- data.frame(ID,States,ToolID,Measurement,Location)
```

I am trying to do some data manipulation on this data frame using the following conditions

```
For each ID (grouped),     
    if States = NA, then the Status = "No Status"
    if States column contains at least(count >=) 1 "All Locked", then the Status = "Lock Status"
    if States column doesn't contain (count =0)  "All Locked", then the Status = "No Lock Status"
```

My desired output is

```
  ID ToolID Measurement Location         Status
   1     NA      Length       US      No Status
   2     NA     Breadth       US      No status
   3    SWP       Width       UK    Lock Status
   4    SWP      Height       UK No Lock Status
   5    SWP        Time       US    Lock Status
   6    SWP        Mass       UK No Lock Status
```

I am trying to do it this way but getting the logic wrong

```
df1$Status <- ifelse(df1$States == NA, "No Status",
                ifelse((count(df1$States == "All Locked") >=1),
                  "Lock Status",
                  ifelse((count(df1$States == "All Locked") <1),
                    "No Lock Status", NA)))
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I would like to apply to my bigger dataset and so a fast solution would help me a lot.

Comment: Looks like you want the summarized output instead of mutate.  So include a `distinct` after the `ungroup`

Comment: I already did distinct on your code sample but as per the logic it returns 2 rows for id =5 when I only need 1 row. please see my comment below to your solution.

Comment: It is not clear in the logic to remove the rows

Comment: Please clarify your desired output for ToolID 5; it has 2/3 locked states; according to the intent of your last `ifelse(..., NA)` it should give Status=NA? not "All Locked". See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NA` elements, use `is.na` and `dplyr::count` works on `data.frame/tbl`s.

Here, we group by 'ID', check `if` there is at least one `"All Locked"` in 'States' column then change it to "All Locked" for the entire group (Instead of using `mutate` to do this, change it within the `group_by` and `add=TRUE` for adding a new grouping variable along with the existing group), get the group by frequency of 'ID' and 'States' and then based on the condition, change the values in 'States'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  group_by(States = if("All Locked" %in% States) "All Locked" 
              else States, add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(States = c("No Lock Status", "Lock Status")[1+ 
                (States == "All Locked" & n >=1)], 
          States = replace(States, is.na(States), "No Status")) %>%
  select(-n) %>% 
  distinct
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution akrun but it is not grouping by ID. I would like only one row per ID. Please see my desired output. I didn't mention "for each ID" in my question previously but now edited it. apologies for that.

Comment: @Sharath The grouping is only to get the frequency count after that it is ungrouped. It is as per your logic showed where `count` should get the frequency by group

Comment: @Sharath Your expected output is 6 rows while the input data is more

Comment: What I meant is this: In the above case, the ID = 5 has 3 values for states, "All locked", "All locked" "All Not Locked", since the count of states having "All locked" is greater than 1, then it should return only 1 row per ID with the status saying "Lock Status". For id =6, it doesnt have any "All locked" in states, and so it should return only 1 row with the status saying "No Lock Status". Am I making sense? I am sorry if I am confusing you.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much for your help. I apologize for the confusion in explaining what I wanted.

Comment: Could you add some comment explaining the cleverness behind `group_by(States = if("All Locked" %in% States) "All Locked" else States, add = TRUE) ...` ? I think `dplyr::case_when` is clearer.

Comment: @smci Sure, you are right. `case_when` makes it more easier to understand

Comment: I mean the rolling `group_by(States = if("All Locked" %in% States) "All Locked" else States, add = TRUE)` is clever, but I suspect it's slow.

Comment: See my answer, we can directly go to `summarize(Status = sum(States=="All Locked")/n() )` and calculate the proportion locked between 0..1 or NA. Didn't even need to use the `all()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short clean idiom using [`dplyr::case_when`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/case_when).
First we compute `Status` as the summary statistic proportion of States which are "All Locked" (0..1 or NA), then we immediately recycle `Status` column into the corresponding string output:

```
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>%

    summarize(ToolID=ToolID[1], Measurement=Measurement[1], Location=Location[1],
      Status = sum( States=="All Locked")/n() ) %>%

    mutate(Status = case_when(
      is.na(Status)         ~ "No Status",
      Status == 1           ~ "Lock Status",
      Status == 0           ~ "No Lock Status",
      between(Status, 0, 1) ~ as.character(NA) ))
```

Output:

```
     ID ToolID Measurement Location Status        
  <dbl> <fctr> <fctr>      <fctr>   <chr>         
1  1.00 NA     Length      US       No Status     
2  2.00 NA     Breadth     US       No Status     
3  3.00 SWP    Width       UK       Lock Status   
4  4.00 SWP    Height      UK       No Lock Status
5  5.00 SWP    Time        US       NA            
6  6.00 SWP    Mass        UK       No Lock Status
```

Comment: Note the output for ToolID 5; it has 2/3 locked states; according to the intent of your last `ifelse(..., NA)` it should give Status=NA? not "All Locked".

Answer (score 1):

The `any()` function is well suited for aggregation, here. *Joining with a lookup table* converts `NA`, `TRUE`, and `FALSE`, resp.,  into the `Status` values the OP expects.

The approach can be implemented in `data.table` syntax as well as `dplyr` style.

#### Create lookup table

This will be used by the `data.table` and the `dplyr` variants.

```
library(data.table)
lut <- data.table(st = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE), 
                  Status = c("No Status", "Lock Status", "No Lock Status"))
```

#### `data.table` version

```
library(data.table)
# aggregate by ID
agg <- setDT(df1)[, .(st = any(States == "All Locked")), by = ID][
  #  join with lookup table
  lut, on = "st"][, -"st"]
# join with df1 to prepend other columns
unique(df1[, -"States"])[agg, on = "ID"]
```

> ```
>    ID ToolID Measurement Location         Status
> 1:  1   <NA>      Length       US      No Status
> 2:  2   <NA>     Breadth       US      No Status
> 3:  3    SWP       Width       UK    Lock Status
> 4:  5    SWP        Time       US    Lock Status
> 5:  4    SWP      Height       UK No Lock Status
> 6:  6    SWP        Mass       UK No Lock Status
> ```

#### `dplyr` version

```
library(dplyr)
agg <-df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(st = any(States == "All Locked")) %>% 
  left_join(lut) %>% 
  select(-st)
df1 %>% 
  select(-States) %>%  
  unique() %>% 
  left_join(agg)
```

> ```
>   ID ToolID Measurement Location         Status
> 1  1   <NA>      Length       US      No Status
> 2  2   <NA>     Breadth       US      No Status
> 3  3    SWP       Width       UK    Lock Status
> 4  4    SWP      Height       UK No Lock Status
> 5  5    SWP        Time       US    Lock Status
> 6  6    SWP        Mass       UK No Lock Status
> ```